# Unable to perform Session State in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I was trying to perform Session State in ASP.NET, but it always start from 1 in  different pages.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["count"] = 0;
        }

        int count = (int)Session["count"];
        count++;
        Label1.Text = count.ToString();
        Session["count"] = count;
    }

    // In Global.asax

    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

      protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
      }

      void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {                                // start of Session
          Session["count"] = 0;
      }

      void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }
    }
```

I expect the count continues but not starts from 1 after re-visit the webform. Thanks!

Comment: It will work if you post back to next page. GET will not show the expected behavior. POST something to next page, your code will work fine. GET will always reset the variable. You can also try removing the post back condition. it will work as expected, as you are setting session variable on app start.

Comment: A complete post back does not mean session is abandoned. It seems by the way you worded the question that is what you are expecting. You are storing an application specific session variable but resetting it on all page loads. Should it be incremented on every page load?

Comment: Thanks @Tushar! It works after I remove the post back condition. :)

Comment: Thanks @Ross Bush! Yes, I want the incremented count be on every page load, but I didn't realise what I did was keep resetting the variable on all page loads..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display the total active user on your site, use application object instead of session object and on session_start you increase count and on session_end, decrease count.

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Application["count"] = 0;
  }

  void Session_Start()
  {                                // start of Session
      Application["count"] += 1;
  }

  void Session_End()
  {
      Application["count"] -= 1;
  }
```